# Change DevExpress GridView row back color after SetFocusedRowIndex(-1) by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, client-side-scripting

I have a client side function by JavaScipt for `FocusedRowChanged` in my `ASPxGridView`.
In this function I post `gvMore.GetFocusedRowIndex()` to my `CallBackPanel` `PerformCallback`.
I save `FocusedRowIndex` in to ri variable ( `var ri = gvMore.GetFocusedRowIndex();` )
and then I remove focus for row ( `gvMore.SetFocusedRowIndex(-1);` )
Now how can I Change `GridView` `row[ri]` color after `SetFocusedRowIndex(-1);` ?

```
function OnGridFocusedRowChanged() {
    if (gvMore.GetFocusedRowIndex() > -1)
        CallBackPanel_FindPlcyCar.PerformCallback(gvMore.GetFocusedRowIndex());
    var ri = gvMore.GetFocusedRowIndex();
    gvMore.SetFocusedRowIndex(-1);
 // *???*
}
```

what JavaScript code is necessary for *???* Line?

Please answer here and do not redirect me to another link please.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried something ? What are the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used allowrowselect instead of allowrowfocus. 
And RowClick client side Event.
And e.visibleIndex in RowClick client side Event.
allowrowselect changes the backcolor itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
OnHtmlRowPrepared="gvMore_HtmlRowPrepared"
```

on the aspx file at the ASPxGridview tag and implement it as follows on the cs file:

```
public protected gvMore_HtmlRowPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("id",e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

On the client side you can then change the // *???* part with

```
document.getElementById(ri).style.Background = "#122334"
```

or whatever other color you might want.
I have not executed the code, and there might be more ins and outs but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Finally I used allowrowselect instead of allowrowfocus.
And RowClick client side Event.